# How to find objects with the same property values in an Array of Objects in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, keyvaluepair

I have an array of objects

```
var myArray = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Bar Foo', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
];
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
commonIdsObjects = [
  {id: 3, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'},

]
```

Comment: what if there are other objects with similar id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the output to be a single array containing all the duplicate entries, even if some of those entries have different ids.  For example, if you had added `{id: 2, name: 'Fishy Joe', email: 'com@foo.bar'}` to `myArray`, the resulting `commonIdsObjects` would be an array of four items: two for `id: 2` and two for `id: 3`. If this is not what you want then you should take care to specify exactly the expected behavior.

Anyway, assuming you have a type corresponding to the elements of `myArray`, like this:

```
type Elem = typeof myArray[number];
```

And assuming your target runtime has access to the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) methods, then you can write

```
const commonIdsObjects = Object.values(
    myArray.reduce<{ [k: number]: Elem[] }>(
        (a, v) => ((a[v.id] || (a[v.id] = [])).push(v), a), {}
    )
).filter(c => c.length > 1).flat(1);
```

What we're doing is using `myArray.reduce()` to build an object whose keys correspond to your elements' `id` values, and whose values are arrays of elements with those `id`.  We convert this object into an array of arrays of elements, keep only those whose lengths are more than one (i.e., any id with more than one element corresponding to it), and flatten into a single array.

This will produce the desired result:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(commonIdsObjects));
// [{"id":3,"name":"Joe Ocean","email":"joe@ocean.com"},
//  {"id":3,"name":"Jenny Block","email":"foo@bar.com"}]
```

If you don't have access to `Object.values()` and `[].flat()` you can use `Object.keys()` and `[].reduce()` instead:

```
type ElemsById = { [k: string]: Elem[] }
const commonIdsObjects2 = ((o: ElemsById) => Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k]))(
    myArray.reduce<ElemsById>(
        (a, v) => ((a[v.id] || (a[v.id] = [])).push(v), a), {}))
    .filter(c => c.length > 1).reduce<Elem[]>((a, v) => (a.push(...v), a), []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(commonIdsObjects2)); // same
```

which is essentially the same algorithm.  Or you could do this algorithm the purely-imperative-programming way with various `for` loops:

```
const elemsById: ElemsById = {};
for (let v of myArray) {
    if (!elemsById[v.id]) {
        elemsById[v.id] = []
    }
    elemsById[v.id].push(v);
}
const commonIdsObjects3: Elem[] = []
for (let k in elemsById) {
    if (elemsById[k].length <= 1) {
        continue;
    }
    for (let v of elemsById[k]) {
        commonIdsObjects3.push(v);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(commonIdsObjects3)); // same
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/G4QwTgBAtgnggmMIYQLwQNoFgBQF8QDeEAlgCYBcEAjADQQB2IUAplQOQBiA9txAELh29FlBAkANhwBmvAAIAjcADoAxtyjsIAX1q4CRUpQgAmek1YdBkHt2ERR4qRHZKwc2dzUatu-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-H4nn+GJUJ-LdQU8CFwBw0CiCXGD73g1gnxiXckn3Q80L-M8L04oDcMYlc10fP9nxqOp30-biKL-ACug0a8QLhVSESRCBdSgFZ+BgZkMRVNUIB7Ps821TS0SgfUdBrGk6RHMcWT5KcVhMDEHW4HVLJ0vSyBtVA7WcgVGhYGAxW4YMxDuZ5GkzbhVT6IMTQMKUbmUWV5SVLSfOZY04wMC0rX8u0HW9Z1XQgD0vR9CqA0S4MHieZ5wwgSNo20IM42UZMJFTMB00zbNcwLRYixoYMMoVFhFS0-VjUKiBrUzC0Qya5R1patrMES6scGpOsGwaZs207btZl7ftB2HKBRyZJzJy5VyZ0pPba3mFhvN05kvNEHKyAM7RYVkSBnjReZgDA3FUuQG1CDjAd7QAQg+36vrIGq-Vh-KCBR7S0Yx-1trjWNTQcT7fIJ1awxhXASf2+ybscid+W5YIfqswn9VwYH7TBiBYr7MnUd8rHSYR55cb+hKc2qEaIEVdASyIbH8GpWY+xFWEDBJgwedBlhwchoW8YpxpEuV0mDHpO7mZc4IqeamnSZJuna3rFhG2O9suxMy6h2t8cgtZzrVJel6IFGSOo+jmPY7j+OE8TmP9DnAAZRl+AAJTgTOAE0IAAEWRThW3Dvs+ukEBEniB7ZgAYTesAFVmM4LYMIURRWRUABVjU8wwMBWKhfbMqhu50SqIGuZBU5IEKe8NKEx-1LWCA70Vnn7mMl9a2oV9p3By72Svq+nmAF7bghpDLWZFQAVWNJZVioO-9Tfvp38-vp6DIFg7iWKgAB2Her8KSk2vuWe+j9lhDwgKAr+X8f5-wARAAAbCA-e4Cb5QOeE-WB8CP6EPfkg-+iwqAAFYMFgN1tgh+uCYEvwQYQkhKCAAsVDV74AgbfOheDGFEOYRAX+pCQgcLjNwnBfC4GIKEcgshpgxFYMgbwhh0jBHCKWAAfioCWfhnCIASJUc-NRLD5EAAZFE0OUcaDRixtGMBJGSHeyQYCYJJkAA)

Comment: I have a bigger problem, I tried to apply some logic related to this one but didn't work

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439450/typescript-how-to-get-objects-with-the-same-property-values-but-different-keys

Answer (score 1):

```
  var myArray = [
{ id: 1, name: "Foo Bar", email: "foo@bar.com" },
{ id: 2, name: "Bar Foo", email: "bar@foo.com" },
{ id: 3, name: "Joe Ocean", email: "joe@ocean.com" },
{ id: 3, name: "Jenny Block", email: "foo@bar.com" }];

const commonIdsObjects = myArray.filter(x => x.id === 3);

console.log(commonIdsObjects);
```