# typescript: How to get objects with the same property values but different keys from 2 different sets of Objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, ngrx, keyvaluepair

I have to sets of Json got from the form the state data

```
objetSet1:
  {id: 12, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 23, name: 'Bar Foo', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 61, name: 'Barbell', email: 'barbell@mail.com'},
  {id: 45, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'}

objectSet2:
  {ObjectId:15, name: 'someone', email: 'someone@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 23, name: 'sometwo', email: 'sometwo@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 72, name: 'seven ', email: 'seven@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 23, name: 'five ', email: 'five@mail.com'}
```

I was actually looking for a way to get this expression to be dynamic

```
objectSet2 = objectSet2.filter(object => object.ObjectId === '23')
```

instead of 23 static value, the value from objectSet1 corresponding

**the result should contain Item with ids present on the first object set**

expected output:

```
objectSet2:
      {ObjectId: 23, name: 'sometwo', email: 'sometwo@mail.com'},
      {ObjectId: 23, name: 'five ', email: 'five@mail.com'}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  What does "the value from objectSet1 corresponding" mean?

Comment: Ideally you would provide a [mcve] as described in [ask] that someone can drop into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) with enough use cases so that people who want to help you can have a good chance of giving you a relevant answer.

Comment: Do you mean the result should contain the items with ids present on the first object set?

Comment: right I am really sorry for the lack of precision and presentation of my questions...
and yes that I what I mean, the result should contain Item with ids present on the first object set

Comment: @YoannEddy - as you get feedback like that from nilsandry you should edit your question to make it clearer. You replied to the comment with a comment, but the question is no clearer unless someone reads all the comments. Comments also can be and are deleted over time, so anything not in the question won't help future readers.

Comment: @StephenP Thank you for the feedback. I am totally new to asking questions over here...  I edited and hope that it appears to be more clear.. please let me know if more details are required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy were close, just needed to add a new filter like this:

```js
objetSet1 = [{id: 12, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 23, name: 'Bar Foo', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 61, name: 'Barbell', email: 'barbell@mail.com'},
  {id: 45, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'}];
  
  objectSet2 = [{ObjectId:15, name: 'someone', email: 'someone@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 23, name: 'sometwo', email: 'sometwo@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 72, name: 'seven ', email: 'seven@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 23, name: 'five ', email: 'five@mail.com'}];
  
 var result = objectSet2.filter((obj2)=>objetSet1.filter((obj1)=>obj1.id==obj2.ObjectId).length>0)
 
 console.log(result);
```

Please note `obj1.id==obj2.ObjectId` comparison. It's returning true when the count of positive matches on the inner filter is greater than zero. Then this is the answer for the outer filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a set of ids from the first array:

```
  const ids = new Set(objectSet1.map(object => object.id));
```

Then you can check wether objects from the second array are in that set

```
  ids.has(object.ObjectId)
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work out. but thanks for your time and consideration

Answer (score 0):

This combines Jonas Wilms and Ictus' answers in a way that I think is slightly clearer, and I've commented the code for future readers to know what's being done.

```js
// Define Yoann Eddy's original two sets of objects, but as Arrays
let objectSet1 = [
  {id: 12, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 23, name: 'Bar Foo', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 61, name: 'Barbell', email: 'barbell@mail.com'},
  {id: 45, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'}
];

let objectSet2 = [
  {ObjectId:15, name: 'someone', email: 'someone@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 23, name: 'sometwo', email: 'sometwo@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 72, name: 'seven ', email: 'seven@mail.com'},
  {ObjectId: 23, name: 'five ', email: 'five@mail.com'}
];

// Get just the ID numbers from the first set
let ids = new Set(objectSet1.map(o => o.id));

// Filter the second set, keeping only the objects that have
// an object.ObjectId that is in the first set of IDs
let result = objectSet2.filter(o => ids.has(o.ObjectId));

console.log(result);
```

Ictus's all-in-one line does the job, but will be harder to maintain simply because it's harder to understand by a colleague (or your future self)